# Put a ListActivity "in" my main activity view

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, android-activity

I will try to phrase this question more succinctly:

Say I have a completely functioning **ListActivty** say .. say, GreenListActivity.

How do I "put that" GreenListActivity **inside another existing activity layout** ?  Thanks!

---

My android MainActivity has an xml file activity_main.xml, like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                tools:context="com.client.app.MainActivity">

    // some other images, buttons widgets, etc here

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/feedView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            ..etc..
            android:scrollbars="none"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    // some other images, buttons widgets, etc here

</RelativeLayout>
```

It all works well, the table is complex, everything works great.  So simply **IN MY MAIN ACTIVITY**, I have...

```
feed = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.feedView);
superDap = new SuperAdapter(this, getLayoutInflater());
feed.setAdapter(superDap);
superDap.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and all the other code relating to the table and cell handling.

Now, I roughly understand ListActivity so I've made a new class...

```
public class MainFeedActivity extends ListActivity
```

I did put that in the manifest.

Now, I understand that generally in the main activity, I will launch the new list activity like this:

```
Intent feedIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainFeedActivity.class);
startActivity( feedIntent );
```

My confusion,

**Question one**, in **activity_main.xml** what do I do to tell it that where I currently have `<ListView android:id="@+id/feedView"` in fact I want to "put in" my new MainFeedActivity ?

**Question two** in fact what should the xml file for MainFeedActivity be like? (Should there be one??)

Sorry, I found many great tutorials fully explaining "how to make a ListActivity",

but,

much to my shame I can't learn how to "put that list" inside the main activity page. That is to say "in" the xml of the main activity.  Or am I just doing it all wrong? (Should the list NOT BE a new activity, maybe?!!) Thanks for any pointers!  Phew

Comment: Hi, Joe. Did you survive your intense ListFragment studies? Did it lead to any result? :D

Comment: I'm up and about and still making massive investigations!!  I think you can be confident of further questions  :)  I'm just waiting the timer to send a bounty :)  Cheers!

Comment: I'd like an enthusiastic answer like `Yeeeeeee! All is finally up an running!!`. Let me know if my effort (and, mostly, yours) sorted any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the xml file should be built:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="209dp" >
</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

//add any additional widgets here
</LinearLayout>
```

In the classes, I would use fragments to implement the above:

```
public static class MainFeedFragment extends ListFragment {

    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // Lauching the Event details screen on selecting a single event
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String ID = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.leader_id))
                        .getText().toString();

                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                        CoreTeamDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra(pid, ID);
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main,container, false);

        //added code to show how adapter connects to list
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),membersList,R.layout.coreteam_item,

        setListAdapter(adapter);
        return rootView;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Wow!  i can't wait to try this!!  Notice in the xml your listView is called "@android:id/list".  Now, how does the class MainFeedFragment "know" that it is to populate "@android:id/list" ? Thanks!

Comment: Added the LinearLayout tag heading, or it would give you errors

Comment: made an edit to the code above in the `onCreateView` method to show how the code populates the list. in my code `memberlist` is an array which contains the list of items you wish to display.

Comment: holy hell - you guys know everything ... this is awesome ....  hell, it looks like **getListView** could be the key to all this!  I didn't know about it!

Comment: Hi @JoeBlow can you please accept the answer if this has helped you?

Answer (score 2):

A ListView can be shown using different methods.

You might use a ListActivity or a ListFragment (if you are to use Fragments).
**In this case**, the list hase to be named **list** (`android:id="@android:id/list"`).
Android will recognize it and manage it.

OR (and I do prefere this one), use a ListView in your design.
**In this case** the ListView can have **any id** (such as `android:id="@+id/feedView"`).
Now you have to thell Android to finde the ListView by id.

In the **same activity** where you have the ListView, you then programmatically create an adapter, fill it and assign it to your ListView.

I hope I cleared your doubts (at least in part).

Anyway, here's a great tutorial on ListViews by Lars Vogel: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Hi, so my class **MainFeedActivity extends ListActivity**. So you mean that class should have an xml file, and, it must have the tag '@+id/list' ?  Thanks!  Regarding your second suggestion .. that is actually what I have already done! Notice my first xml file.  Notice the list is "in" that main activity.  So all my list code, is, in that main activity.  I don't know how the hell to separate it out!  thanks!

Comment: The layout you have shown seems a good candidate for your **ListActivity**. For your main Activity (which extends **Acrivity**), use **some other** xml layout. With a Button or whaterver to call your ListActivity (well, the two Activities could also be **merged into one single** ListActivity, and use that as your main and unique Activity, if you like to)

Comment: Hmm. Say I have a completely functioning ListActivity. (Called, say "DemoListActivity".  Say I have an unrelated page that has four buttons in a column.  Say I want to **put the DemoListActivity on that page** - let's say between buttons 2 and 3.  How the hell is that done?!  Thank you!!

Comment: You can have two buttons to be a sort of "header" and other two as a sort of "footer". Just use two LinearLayouts with `android:orientation="horizontal"`. Give all the buttons `layout_weight="1"` and `layout_width="0dp"` (**0dp**!! or else weights won't work) - Just place your ListView inbetween the header and the footer (it's like a sandwich). Better if you use a RelativeLayout to contain the whole (so, you can anchor the header to the top, the footer to the bottom and THEN put the ListView below the header and above the footer - **it easier to do it than to say it**)

Comment: I forgot to say that, in this case, **weights** are used to distribute the Button widths equally (50% / 50%)

Comment: No, I don't want to put a ListView in the layout.  I want to put in a **DemoListActivity** which is a totally separate, self-contained class.... how to do that??  (I completely understand about weights, thank goodness!  heh!  thanks!)

Comment: You surely have to put a ListView in a layout... or do you want to **go insane doing it all in Java**? Or maybe I'm not understanding. Do you instead mean to have two separate UIs - one with the 4 buttons and another one with the ListView?

Comment: OK, it seems you prefer the second option: `so is it not possible to have an activity (call it "B") which takes care of, operates, on item on the layout of another activity (call it "A"). In my example "A" is indeed the main activity, the main screen. And "B" is a totally separate new ListActivity subclass.` The answer, lucky you, is: "**YES**, you can". You have to start the **DemoListActivity** from a button. In the calling Activity set a Listener (which is sorta callBack) you defined as an interface in your DemoListActivity. In this you'll set the index of the clicked item and get it back.

Comment: Ahh .. **Listener**.  Awesome. I will investigate that. Thanks!  To be clear, I would not use a button to start "B". In fact, "B" would simply start instantly whenever "A" began.  "B" would always be a part of "A", it would always be running/visible whenever "A" is visible.  I'll check out **Listener** thanks!!!!

Comment: So... if B is part of A, you can **merge A and B** (that is, include the ListView in the main - and unique Activity - ListActivity). OR... ladies and gentleman, this is a perfect case for using a **ListFragment** (which is an extension of the Fragment class)! I hope I'm not generating more **entropy**...

Comment: On Listeners. In Activity B you define an Interface with a method, You then call this method when a certain event fires. In Activity A you implement this Interface and override its method. When the method is called in B (when an event in B is fired), you get the result in the overridden Listener method in A.

Comment: In your case, you want to pass the ListView selected index (position)  from B to A. And react appropriately in A.

Comment: Now, Joe, since I'm starting to be confused about your specs... could you, please, post a couple of pictures showing what you have and what you want (a mockup would go)? That would help me to understand how to help you.

Comment: *"you can merge A and B"* .. in fact that's what i have at the moment!!! But the code for the list is right there in "A".  I want the code to be in a separate file, a separate class .. in "B".  (I will check out ListFragment)

Comment: OK, I guess that ListFragment is your preferrable choice, if you want a "code separation".

Comment: OK!  I'm familiar with dialog fragments, so I will figure out list fragments, THANKS!

Comment: Beware: DialogFragments can also appear as **detached windows** (like normal AlertDialogs). Anyway, yes, they are Fragments, and - as **all of them** - they can be attached as part of a container layout.

Comment: Gotchya. To be clear, funnily enough. I have mastered "dialog fragments" as POPUPS, as their own separate window. You know?  It sounds like now I need to learn how the hell to put one in to an existing layout of an existing activity!!  THANKS!!!!!!

Comment: It's not so difficult. `You must "leave a hole" to hold your Fragment where you want it to appear in your main layout. Then put that Fragment in that placeholder and assign it its own layout`. By the way, DialogFragments can hold a ListView... but I don't want to increase your inner entropy level. ;) See this, for reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Got it - I can make a "hole" no problem .. but I'm confused about what xml to use for hole "hole".  But, I'll figure it out!!

Comment: A FrameLayout, with an unique id. Something like `andoid:id="@+id/lvw_placeholder"`

Comment: a FRAME LAYOUT ---------- AHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH .. you know, it could be that is the secret I've been looking for all this time!  pls stand by while I work on it  :)  THANKS

Comment: Here is an example I find very nice, want to share it, just to (probably) help you to see the thing more in depth: http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/08/android-fragment-example.html. It's a ListFragment which opens another Fragment (with a WebView which opens the page selected in the ListFragment)

Comment: I added a bounty to Golem to cover the enormous amount of work Golem has helped me with on this question. Thank you so much, Golem!  Hey, I'm proud that the bounty **pushed you over 10k**!  CHEERS!!  You guys are the 3l33t!!!

Comment: Thank you, Joe. Thank you again. Very much appreciated. I'm happy when I solve someone else's problems and mine as well. And now happier, too!

Answer (score 2):

I think you're a bit confused about what should be done.

If i understand correctly you have a `MainActivity`, which somehow navigates to a different activity that has a list.

- Your main activity has an XML file which defines its own layout, which represents the home screen.
- Your FeedList activity which has a different XML that defines its layout as well.

Those two are different and separate from eachother, when you navigate from HomeActivity to FeedList activity using intents as you mentioned, your new activity will be launched and it's XML will inflated and presented on the screen, so there is no need to put the list 'in' the home activity.

Note: use a normal `Activity` not a `ListActivity` and define the `ListView` you want in the xml of that activity.

feel free to ask if anything is unclear

Comment: "I think you're a bit confused about what should be done." - Yes!  :)  Here's the thing: my MainActivity **does not "go to"** a list view.  My MainActivity has three or four things one the screen, and one of them is a ListView.  Do you see what I mean?  The XML code at the top of this page is All the xml code for the main activity, the main view of the app. My main activity does many things, and, ALL the list view code is in main activity.  Surely, where the main activity has a list view, that can be a "separate" ListActivity??  Sorry if not clear!

Comment: I can only see a ListView in that XML file, what other things are in the activity ? do you mean that you hide some of the components are show the list and the other way around ?

Comment: You're right: the main activity currently has only the list view; and the "pull down to refresh mechanism" that wraps that. Also, it has a lot of code relating to unrelated issues.  Just now, I added a few images and buttons as well on the main items main page; of course over time that could change.  So, right there on the main page is a ListView.  Currently it **works perfectly** but all the code for the ListView is actually there in the MainActivity. Instead of including a "ListView" (as you see there in the xml), how to include "my custom list view" ListActivity class?? (THANKS!)

Comment: You don't need the ListAcitity class, you would only need it if you were navigating to a new activity, now you no longer need a new activity since your main activity has the list
if there is any code related to the list, e.g. adapter or so .. you can use it in the main activity

Comment: Hmm - so is it **not possible** to have an activity (call it "B") which takes care of, operates, on item on the layout of another activity (call it "A").  In my example "A" is indeed the main activity, the main screen.  And "B" is a totally separate new ListActivity subclass.  I'm really sort to take so much of your time, guys

Comment: It's okay :), what i understood from what you said, is that you don't want a second activity, and it's all in one single activity.
So what's with the B activity ? :)

Comment: ok, the "B" activity would be a ListView, that is to say a ListActivity!  Imagine "A" has a number of items .. buttons, images, the usual.  But one of those items is actually ... a "B" .. one of the items (rather than being a usual button, image, whatever) is actually a whole "B" (that is to say, some sort of list display).  (Indeed, there could even be - let's say for example - two or three of the "B" lists running on "A" .. just as you might happen to have two or three buttons on "A".)  That's wot I'm saying!  :)

Comment: If one component is large enough to be a screen itself and should be embedded in your activity .. what you just described is a Fragment